# Canon DSLR camera for web and graphic design photos

Tags: canon, dslr, camera-recommendation, web

I am a web designer and wanting to get into photography, so the photos I take will be mainly for websites, and sometimes for graphic design work.

Can someone please give me some suggestions on which camera model should I get? I prefer Canon. So far I got suggested Canon 1200D and 700D, but not sure on any. I don't want to spend massive money just yet, but at the same time it would be great if the camera has a bit potential so I can keep it for a while.

Thanks! Please let me know if this is dulplicate so I can remove it, but please let me know where I shall look. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this is not a camera recommendation website. A quick peak at our help link at the top of this page has more info.

Comment: Thanks, should I delete it now or would you close it for me?

Comment: I can't delete questions or close questions. I'm just a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's personal preference really. The 700D is a great camera and better than the 1200D in my opinion.

Here is the comparison for both the Canon 1200D and the Canon 700D
http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-EOS-1200D-vs-Canon-EOS-700D.

A good website for second-hand camera gear is MPBPhotographic.

I would also pop in to your nearest camera/electronics store to try some different options before you buy.

Hopefully that answers your question.